# C/C++ read binary files (flaot numbers) at one time

Tags: c++, fread, floating

I was wondering is there a way to speed up fread in C or C++? For example, if I want to read a binary file containing 100 4-byte float numbers. I do:

```
float *data=(float*)calloc(sizeof(float), 100);
float datatmp=0.0;
f=fopen("datafilename","rb");
for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
   fread(&datatmp,4,1,f);
   data[i]=datatm;
}
flcose(f);
```

My question is: can I read all the 100 float numbers at one time and put them in the data array? Will this be faster than using a loop?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, you tell us? If you tried and timed it both ways, what difference, if any, did you measure?

Comment: ***Will this be faster than using a loop?*** Most likely no. Did you enable optimizations  in your compiler? Why do you think reading 100 floats is any type of bottleneck?

Comment: *"can I read all the 100 float numbers at one time and put them in the data array?"* -- I suppose that depends on your programming skill. Can you write the code to do this? Alternatively, can you write some code to read all the 100 float numbers at one time (directly) into the data array? (The simpler code for the latter option is probably more significant than any performance change.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can read all one time.
fread(data,sizeof(float)*100,1,f);